# How do i intialize firebaseui with angular fire

Tags: angular, firebase-authentication, angularfire, firebaseui

I am having trouble using the firebaseui in combination with angular fire. My code for setting up the ui is the following

```
  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const uiConfig = {
      signInOptions: [
        firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
      ],
      callbacks: {
        signInSuccessWithAuthResult: this.onLoginSuccessful.bind(this)
      }
    }
    this.ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(this.afAuth);
    this.ui.start("
firebase
-ui-auth-container", uiConfig);
  }
```

In the console i get the following error:
"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'apiKey'"

The error is thrown for this line:

```
this.ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(this.afAuth);
```

Anyone knows what this probleme might be? The apiKey is defined in the angularfire setup and the authservice works fine, the only problem is with firebaseui